# Texpad (macOS) - highlighting url links/in-text refs using the build-in TexpadteX typesetter

Tags: cross-referencing, highlighting, links, macos, texpad

Do you know any *trick* for including rectangles around references, such as Figures, Tables, and url links, etc. in Texpad editor when the TexpadTeX typesetter is used?

While I can manually change or hide these rectangles (or even alter their colors) using  pdfLaTeX, etc. (i.e. manual typesetter) these commands seem to fail when using the TexpadTex typesetter.

My goal:
[image]

Comment: see the documentation for [hyperref](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref).

Comment: specifically, this is the `[colorlinks=false]` option, which produces the non-printing boxes you're referring to.

Comment: I have tried all sorts of things with _hyperref_ package, for instance `\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}`, but the TexpadTex typesetter either ignores it or throw an error.

Comment: Sounds like it's not actually respecting the `\hypersetup` configurations within the app. This sounds like a problem for their app developers. Try specifying that just before the `begin{document}`. Please provide a MWE of the code you're using in order for others to assist.

Comment: @Jake Apologies for responding so late! I did that; I can share example, but I didn't in the first place, because this is likely a specific question for someone experiences in Texpad, to whom I hoped to meet. For instance, in pdfLaTeX or XeLaTeX, these links are highlighted automatically, or if not, `hypersetup` works flawlessly. This is not the case of Texpad live interpreter, which to my experience ignore any commands of link highlighting and/or colouring, etc..

Comment: It'd be my assumption then that TeXPad's path has converted hyperref's commands to a no-op. Did you check to see what [their bundle management](https://www.texifier.com/docs/apps/typesetting/typesetters/texpadtex/bundle-management) says about whether hyperref is installed and which version it is?